# Why can't I get IEx.pry to work on Windows?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to make IEx.pry work with the following code example:

```
require IEx;

defmodule Example do
  def double_sum(x, y) do
    IEx.pry
    hard_work(x, y)
  end

end

Example.double_sum(1, 2)
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Cannot pry #PID<0.106.0> at lib/example.ex:5. Is an IEx shell running? If you are Windows, you may need to start IEx with the --werl flag.
```

In response I launched iex with --werl and it opened the erlang shell.

In the erlang shell I tried to change directories so that I can launch the file. I did this by typing:

```
cd(c:/Users/william/Desktop/example)
```

I received the following error:

```
(SyntaxError) iex:1: keyword argument must be followed by space after: c:
```

Comment: For the last question, you need to wrap the path in a string: `cd("c:/Users/william/Desktop/example").`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the module code is located in `"c:/Users/william/Desktop/example.ex"`, one might enter the `iex` and force a compilation from there:

```
iex> c "c:/Users/william/Desktop/example.ex"

Request to pry #PID<0.89.0> at /tmp/a.ex:5

    defmodule Example do
      def double_sum(x, y) do
        IEx.pry
        x + y
      end

Allow? [Yn] y

Interactive Elixir (1.5.0-dev) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
pry(1)>
```

Once `"y"` is pressed, you have `pry` prompt entered.

---

Another option would be to use `mix` to manage source code, even such simple source code. `mix` new will create new package. To enable `IEx.pry` support in `mix` one should run `mix` tasks prepended with `iex -S`:

```
iex -S mix # for just iex in mix environment
```

or:

```
iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

to enable `IEx.pry` support in phoenix application.

- [`IEx` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html);
- [Intro to `mix`](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/introduction-to-mix.html).

*Sidenote:* semicolon after `require IEx` is redundant and is a code smell.