# Windows IEx: when to use the --werl flag

Tags: elixir

Attempting to debug a project using `IEx.pry`, I found that I need to use the `--werl` flag. I would refer anyone with potential solutions to this discussion to:

[Should --werl be made default?](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/2682)

My current project has multiple modules and uses Plug.Router. I realize that prying may not be the best debugging technique in this case. Still...

I was curious to learn how to debug with pry so I tested a simple case very similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540289/why-cant-i-get-iex-pry-to-work-on-windows). In short, prying variables from the process environment requires that the IEx shell be running during compile time. This works fine for single modules like in the example linked above; however, my current project requires that I `mix` the project directory. Correct me, perhaps there is a verbose way to compile and run a project directory in the erlang console? At any rate, neither `mix run --no-halt` nor `iex -S mix run` work for prying on Windows (the latter requesting the `--werl` flag).

I then attempted the same task on a much simpler project that did not use Plug and only has one module, a recursive counter. Still, I could not `iex -S mix` this with the `--werl` flag. The Erlang console opens, closes, and the application is not started.
ddddd
I am deducing that I cannot `mix` a project directory with the `--werl` flag, but then when should I use it? And how can I pry in the IEx shell? I would rather not use the Erlang console at all if it is possible.

Reading the Hex docs for IEx:

> Such function [Enum in their example] may not be available on some Windows shells. You may need to pass the --werl flag when starting iex, as in iex --werl for it to work. --werl may be permanently enabled by setting the IEX_WITH_WERL environment variable.

The docs say no more about when to use the `--werl` option.

Clearly, I am new to Elixir, but this does not seem like an obvious distinction even though this issue was raised some 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use both `--werl` and `-S mix` together, you have to put `--werl` before the `-S mix`.

`iex --werl -S mix` will work while `iex -S mix --werl` won't work.